# Magento how to delete products in bulk via SOAP API

Tags: php, api, soap, magento-1.9

I have the following function to delete individual products. It works perfectly but can be very slow if we're dealing with thousands of items. Is there a way to do this in bulk? I tried passing in an array but it didn't work.

```
function delete_magento_product($id) {
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://example.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
    $session = $proxy->login('admin','abc123');
    $result=$proxy->catalogProductDelete($session, $id);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Why not use magmi? https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Comment: Looks interesting. For my purposes I need to use the native API.

Comment: Magmi uses the native api for most of what it does. It is sometimes also faster or large loads

Comment: It seems it needs to be installed on the Magento server which we can't touch.

Comment: Seems best way to do this is by running a delete directly against the DB. Table catalog_product_entity. Strange that the API is so much less flexible.

Comment: You will have more than just 1 table to delete from. There are also the index table adm some product data tables. Otherwise you will polute your DB

Comment: Hi, what about product resources like "media files" - Are they also deleted from DB and/or filesystem ? Do you have any experiences about this topic ? Regards